# Contatenate rows in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, row, bind

I have 12 months sales data for each month. I want to analyze the dataset as a whole.

I have tried using the concat function but It produces not a number (NaN) in my dataframe fields.

In R, cbind function solves this. How do i approach this differently in Python?

I tried using df.concat function to bind the rows cos all the column names are the same for the datasets.

What other options can i explore?

```py
sales_1 = pd.read_csv('Sales_January_2019.csv')
sales_2 = pd.read_csv('Sales_February_2019.csv')
sales_3 = pd.read_csv('Sales_March_2019.csv')
sales_4 = pd.read_csv('Sales_April_2019.csv')
sales_5 = pd.read_csv('Sales_May_2019.csv')
sales_6 = pd.read_csv('Sales_June_2019.csv')
sales_7 = pd.read_csv('Sales_July_2019.csv')
sales_8 = pd.read_csv('Sales_August_2019.csv')
sales_9 = pd.read_csv('Sales_September_2019.csv')
sales_10 = pd.read_csv('Sales_October_2019.csv')
sales_11 = pd.read_csv('Sales_November_2019.csv')
sales_12 = pd.read_csv('Sales_December_2019.csv')
```

I expect all data frame to be merged into one since the column names are the same for all

Comment: provide the data you started with, expected result and the issue you're facing. Its not fully clear on where the issue lies

Comment: Hi naveed, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

perhaps

```
# using concat with the list of the DF that you already read-in to combine into a single DF

pd.concat([sales_1 ,sales_2 ,sales_3 ,sales_4 ,sales_5 ,sales_6 ,sales_7 ,sales_8 ,sales_9 ,sales_10 ,sales_11 ,sales_12 ])
```